# Facebook auth page doesn't close or refresh parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Facebook authentication is working great. I can pull the profile pic and name of the user.  However, when you click login and the facebook prompt comes up I have two problems (in both IE and Chrome).

First off, the window never closes.  It just goes to a blank white page.  This is actually happening to me across the web.  turntable.fm logins do this as well as any fb connected sites I can think of.  it happens to me at work, at home on multiple different PCs.  Is fb broken?  I can't help but think this is related to the other issue...

My page doesn't refresh after I close the (blank) login popup.

So those are the issues.  I tried subscribing to the auth.login event and calling a reload() there, which is what the documentation recommends, but this didn't refresh when you logged in.  It also caused a problem where if you logged out it would just automatically log you back in.  That's why I added the code below to detect a logout and reload.  That actually works.  So how can I make it reload when the popup window is closed, or even better, make the popup window close itself and reload my page?!

all relevant fb code below (I think):

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '123456', // App ID
                channelURL: 'http://www.mydomain.net/channel.html', // Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            //update guest/username if logged in or not
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        $('#UserMenu').show();
                        $('#Login').hide();
                        $('#fbpic').html('<img alt="Account Picture" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.username + '/picture" />');
                        $('#AccountName').html(response.name);
                        getVentID(response.id, response.name);
                        $('#Logout').show();
                    });
                } else {
                    //not logged in to facebook
                }
            });

            $('#Logout').live('click', function () {
                FB.logout(function (response) {
                    // user is now logged out
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            });

            //subscribe to login changes
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {

            });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        } (document));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I had Facebook "installed" in Chrome! Uninstall and now it works everywhere. SOOO happy!